# Lua unprotected error using lua_pcall

Tags: lua

I'm using a Lua Protected call, but I'm getting an unprotected error:

```
lua_getfield( m_L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "startIteration" );    // 1
if( lua_isfunction( m_L, -1 ) ){
    lua_pushnumber( m_L, n );                               // 2
    auto ret = lua_pcall( m_L, 1, 0, 0 );                   // 0
    checkLuaReturn( m_L, ret );
}else{
    lua_pop( m_L, 1 );                                      // 0
}
```

And the error is:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (../example/ex01.lua:31: attempt to index global 'raster' (a nil value))
```

And the Lua code is:

```
function startIteration( num )
   io.write( "Start iteration " .. num .. "\n" )
   raster.grass.save( "output.png" )
end
```

How can I solver it, to get a REAL protected call?

update: fixed extra pop

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that actually executes the Lua script? At least the call to `lua_pcall` seems fine, so the problem may be hiding somewhere else. However, there is a problem with the first `lua_pop` in the if branch. You pass 0 as a 3rd argument to `lua_pcall`, so that pop will only be valid if an error occured. Remembet that the pcall consumes both the function and its arguments from the stack.

Comment: I'm sure that this is the place tha cals the script, I don't use "startIteration" in other places.

Comment: Also, the lua_pop is to remove the value that lua_getfield push into the stack. The error value is removed in checkLuaReturn funcion.

Comment: But that's the point: `lua_pcall` [already removed](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall) the value from `lua_getfield`. So after the `lua_pop` your stack is at `-1` and not at `0`.

Comment: you're rigth @ComicSansMS, it remove the extra pop, but the error persist

Comment: Is the message `Start iteration...` printed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this has nothing to do with your lua_pcall() but rather with your lua code.
The line `raster.grass.save( "output.png" )`  is where the error is.

Try channging that to something like this:

```
if raster and type(raster) == 'table' then
    if raster.grass and type(raster.grass) then
        raster.grass.save()
    end
end
```

But, that's not going to solve your issue, the issue is that you're calling a member of the variable `raster` before `raster` was even created.

Comment: The question is why Lua panics given that the call is protected.

Comment: as @lhf says, the problem is the lua panic, not that there is errors in lua code. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it stumped me for a while. The answer on this thread misses the point of the question. OP is using `lua_pcall`, yet is still receiving an unprotected error.

In my case, the Lua stack was corrupted. I ran a function that did not return a value, but popped a value off the stack anyway. Later, when I ran `lua_pcall` on an unrelated function, I got an unprotected error. Correcting the error of popping off the stack fixed it.